# RewriteCond query string to clean URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm fighting .htaccess for approx. 4 hours.
Trying to create a simple Rewritecond :

**from:**

```
example.com/post.php?id=1&url=something
```

**to:**

```
example.com/news/1/something
```

this gives me 404:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&url=([A-Za-z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ /news/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: When do you get the 404, before or after the rewrite? If you request `/news/1/something` directly, then everything works as it is supposed to?

Comment: Change `^post\.php$` to `^/?post\.php`

Comment: i prefer marshalling ALL requests through an index.php, then using a routing package like `symfony/routing` or similar. So much easier https://github.com/symfony/routing

Comment: @misorude  i׳m getting 404 after rewrite. (example/news/1/something)

Comment: I have to insist. Does `/news/` exist ? Are there any more `RewriteRules` that further Rewrite this? You will need some kind of front controller to handle the request like `post.php` is doing now.

Comment: @msg no, /news/ does not exist. I'm trying to focus on reading symfony/routing documentation like mentioned above.

Comment: im not using any other

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I think you got this backwards. If you want to show your current `post.php` page when accessing `/news`, the rule you need is:

```
RewriteRule news/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&url=$2
```